# Upload file on pre_update_option_{option_name}

Tags: options

is there a way to upload a file while saving options in WP ?
I have this option setting (save is binded to options.php) and need to upload and store a file on server

[image]

and cannot find the file in update_option_{option_name}:

```
add_action('init', array($this,'upload_credentials'), 10);
function upload_credentials( ) {
  //CRM_adv_settings is the option name
  add_filter( 'pre_update_option_CRM_adv_settings', array($this,'system_save_file'), 10, 2 );
}

function system_save_file($new_value, $old_value){
  //$rawData = file_get_contents("php://input");
  $f=$_FILES;
  $p=$_POST;
}
```

Cannot find $_FILES, in $_POST there's the filename; tried several variation about `update_option` and `pre_update_option` but no success, any idea?

Comment: "save is binded to options.php" - so you're using the settings API?

Comment: yes, the 'save' pass in my function system_save_file() but I don't find the `$_FILE` global in there

Comment: Does your form tag have the `enctype` attribute - `enctype="multipart/form-data"`?

Comment: thanks a lot, that was ! if you want to answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm quite sure the problem is **not** with the WordPress hook you're using. Instead, the following:

> Cannot find `$_FILES`, in `$_POST`, there's the filename

.. is most likely because your form tag (`<form>`) does not have the required [`enctype` attribute](https://html.com/attributes/form-enctype/) which must be set to `multipart/form-data` to make file upload input works in that the file gets uploaded to the server — without setting the `enctype` to `multipart/form-data`, the input still works (i.e. you can select a file that you want to upload), but it'll work like a standard input field where the browser submits only the file name (e.g. `my-image.png`) and not the actual file itself (which PHP puts in the `$_FILES`).

So make sure your form tag has the attribute `enctype="multipart/form-data"`:

```html
<form method="post" action="options.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    ...
</form>
```